# adding mouse event to change the color of simple circle

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I draw a circle and trying to add mouse event, that change the color of the circle i cannot find good sources

Here is the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define window_width  1080  
#define window_height 720 
void drawFilledSun() {
    //static float angle;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -10);
    int i, x, y;
    double radius = 0.30;
    //glColor3ub(253, 184, 19);     
    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    double twicePi = 2.0 * 3.142;
    x = 0, y = 0;
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN); //BEGIN CIRCLE
    glVertex2f(x, y); // center of circle
    for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        glVertex2f(
            (x + (radius * cos(i * twicePi / 20))), (y + (radius * sin(i * twicePi / 20)))
        );
    }
    glEnd(); //END
}
void main_loop_function() {
    int c;
    drawFilledSun();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    c = getchar();
}
void GL_Setup(int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gluPerspective(45, (float)width / height, .1, 100);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(window_width, window_height);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutCreateWindow("GLUT Example!!!");
    glutIdleFunc(main_loop_function);
    GL_Setup(window_width, window_height);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: What isn't working with this code?

Comment: What's the question?  Are you asking how to write mouse button/motion callbacks?  Figure out what you want to ask & edit that into the question.

Comment: i could make circle with two ways and this code is working i want to add the feature to add mouse event, that change the color of the circle i cannot find a way

Comment: Specify what you want to do in the question.

Comment: i have this question too if you can help i appreciate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490759/simple-pallet-for-colors @genpfault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an array for the red green and blue color components of the sun and a color index:

```cpp
int color_i = 0;
GLubyte color[][3] = { {255, 0, 0 }, {253, 184, 19} };
```

Use the color arrays to set the color attribute

```cpp
void drawFilledSun() {
     // [...]

     glColor3ubv(color[color_i]);
```

Get rid of the `getchar` in `main_loop_function`, it prevents the window from responding. But call [`glutPostRedisplay`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node20.html) for continuously updating the window:

```cpp
void main_loop_function() {
    drawFilledSun();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Use [`glutDisplayFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html) rather than [`glutIdleFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node63.html) and add a [`glutMouseFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node50.html) callback:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // [...]

    glutDisplayFunc(main_loop_function);
    glutMouseFunc( mouseFunc );
```

Change the color index in the mouse callback:

```cpp
void mouseFunc(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        color_i = (color_i == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

---

See the example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define window_width  1080  
#define window_height 720

int color_i = 0;
GLubyte color[][3] = { {255, 0, 0 }, {253, 184, 19} };

void drawFilledSun() {
    //static float angle;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -10);
    int i, x, y;
    double radius = 0.30;
    glColor3ubv(color[color_i]);
    double twicePi = 2.0 * 3.142;
    x = 0, y = 0;
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN); //BEGIN CIRCLE
    glVertex2f(x, y); // center of circle
    for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        glVertex2f(
            (x + (radius * cos(i * twicePi / 20))), (y + (radius * sin(i * twicePi / 20)))
        );
    }
    glEnd(); //END
}

void main_loop_function() {
    drawFilledSun();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void GL_Setup(int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gluPerspective(45, (float)width / height, .1, 100);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void mouseFunc(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        color_i = (color_i == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(window_width, window_height);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutCreateWindow("GLUT Example!!!");
    glutDisplayFunc(main_loop_function);
    glutMouseFunc( mouseFunc );
    GL_Setup(window_width, window_height);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GLFW` provided some callback functions which you need such as `glfwSetCursorPosCallback`.

In this case you can simply check it by a `if` branch while drawing, `main_loop_function` in your code. The rest work is about C/C++, and there are many paths to reach it such as `kbhit`.

By the way, it's not elegant to ues several naming styles.